terra::as.data.frame Naming when dealing with multiple layers
When using as.data.frame to handle multiple layers, for the merged layer all the naming is lyr.1. Is there a better way to solve this naming problem?
library(terra)

m <- matrix(1:25, nrow=5, ncol=5)
rm <- rast(m)
n <- matrix(rep(5,time=25),nrow = 5,ncol = 5)
rn <- rast(n)

dt <- c(rm,rn)
data <- terra::as.data.frame(dt,xy=TRUE)
head(data)

> head(data)
    x   y lyr.1 lyr.1
1 0.5 4.5     1     5
2 1.5 4.5     6     5
3 2.5 4.5    11     5
4 3.5 4.5    16     5
5 4.5 4.5    21     5
6 0.5 3.5     2     5

Is it possible to bring the original names into the layers (in the example: rm and rn)?

You can set the layer names with names<-
Your data
library(terra)
rm <- matrix(1:25, nrow=5, ncol=5) |> rast()
rn <- matrix(rep(5,time=25),nrow = 5,ncol = 5) |> rast()
dt <- c(rm, rn)

set the names
names(dt) <- c("A", "B")
terra::as.data.frame(dt,xy=TRUE) |> head(2)
#    x   y A B
#1 0.5 4.5 1 5
#2 1.5 4.5 6 5

You could also do
dt <- terra::rast(c(A=rm, B=rn))
terra::as.data.frame(dt,xy=TRUE) |> head(2)
#    x   y A B
#1 0.5 4.5 1 5
#2 1.5 4.5 6 5


Thank you! I realized it's the difference between the name of the data in the computing environment and the name of the internal coordinates of the data！

That is correct. There is a difference between the R variable name (of a SpatRaster), and the layer name(s) of that object.

Got it. Thank you very much.
